# Ho To Perform U-Substitution On Given Intergal

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int{x^2\sqrt{2+x}}\ {dx}$$

I haven't been able to find what u should be in this integral, where should I start?

I've gotten as far as:

let $u = 2 + x$; $du=\frac{1}{x}dx$

Comment: Let $u = 2 + x$ and do some algebra to express $x^2$.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work to well, i'll try again tho.

Comment: If you post what you can get when you try that, perhaps we can point out any mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=2+x\;\Rightarrow\; x=u-2\;\Rightarrow\; dx=du$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\int x^2\sqrt{2+x}\ dx&=\int (u-2)^2\sqrt{u}\ du\\
&=\int (u^2-4u+4)\ u^{\frac12}\ du\\
&=\int \left(u^{\frac52}-4u^{\frac32}+4u^{\frac12}\right)\ du
\end{align}
$$
or let $u^2=2+x\;\Rightarrow\; x=u^2-2\;\Rightarrow\; dx=2u\ du$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\int x^2\sqrt{2+x}\ dx&=\int (u^2-2)^2u\cdot 2u\ du\\
&=2\int (u^4-4u^2+4)\ u^{2}\ du\\
&=2\int \left(u^{6}-4u^{4}+4u^{2}\right)\ du.
\end{align}
$$